# $_FILES population - Can it be assumed that all fields will always be populated if one of them is?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm dealing with upload/file validation now, and have a quick question.

If I first create a conditional/if statement that checks if one of the $_FILES fields is set and not empty, can I assume from within that control statement that all of the related fields are already set as well?

Code to illustrate:

```
if (!empty($_FILES['some_name']['name']) {

    /** Can I now absolutey do this? */
    $size = $_FILES['name']['size']

    /** Or is this still the proper approach? */
    if (!empty($_FILES['some_name']['size']) {

        $size = $_FILES['some_name']['size']; 

    }

}
```

Is there ever any situation on the PHP platform where the rest of $_FILES might not be populated?

I think I can assume that if that is happening, there are bigger problems on the server to worry about than the $_FILES not being populated?

Comment: Yes, I would assume that is a safe assumption.  If it isn't, something is definitely broken.